# Display query and result on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently having a two page application which lets the user enter the data and hit submit and the next page opens with the Query result in a grid. like below

home.html

[image]

```
  <form name="homeForm">
<div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">From Date</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="fromDate"
                   name="fromDate"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="request.fromDate"
                   is-open="popup1.opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                   required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.fromDate.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.fromDate.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">To Date</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="toDate"
                   name="toDate"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="request.toDate"
                   is-open="popup2.opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                   required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.toDate.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.toDate.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(homeForm)">Clear</button>
            <!--ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" -->
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Views/Angular/results.html" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

result.html
[image]

```
<div>
 <h4 class="text-primary">Search Results</h4>
 <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-around">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoading" md-diameter="150"></md-progress-circular>
</div>
<div id="gridStyle" ng-if="gridOptions.data"
     ui-grid="gridOptions"
     class="myGrid"
     ui-grid-resize-columns
     ui-grid-pagination
     ui-grid-selection
     ui-grid-auto-resize
     ui-grid-cellNav
     ui-grid-exporter>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Now I am trying to put all the query and the query result together in a page. Like all the inputs/buttons on the left and the grid on the right.

Adding the code in to Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gBvLCSUr7rrbEry68Hw4?p=catalogue)

Do I need to add one more html page that will have both these html, and I should be calling that in the app.js? I am very new to AngularJS not sure how can I do this

Comment: The `angular` tag refers to Angular 2+, so I've removed that tag for you. Also, that Plunker link appears to go to an empty Plunker

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a view component, which will include your two components which will become the child components of the newly added view.

Check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03) tutorial to learn the concept.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example

Comment: I updated my comment with the proper section on official tutorial page, where you can learn the basic concepts to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asynchronous XHTML And JavaScript (AJAX) to have everything on a single page, without loading a different page, which is what I would do unless you have requirements to display results on a separate page.

Considering you have `type=button` for the submit button, it appears AJAX was intended since this will prevent the page from reloading when the submit button is clicked.

Basically, in the `createRequest()` function, send the query parameters (which appear to be included in the `homeForm` argument) to the query service. When the response is received, update the `gridOptions.data` with the values you want displayed in the table... Angular should take care of the rest.